# reading in missing data c# input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, input, missing-data

I am new to C#. I have been trying to read in a dataset with missing data. After reading in the headers, I read in the rest of the file using:

```
List<int> idList = new List<int>();
List<int[]> valList = new List<int[]>();
string line = sr.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    string[] lineParts = line.Split(delimiters);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[0]);
    idList.Add(id);

    int[] vals = new int[numTests];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        vals[i] = Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[i + 1]);
    }
    valList.Add(vals);
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
childIDs = idList.ToArray();
int[][] values = valList.ToArray();
```

When I run this, I get the error message "Input string was not in a correct format." I can't quite figure out how to read in the missing data. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what is the contents of the `line`? I suppose by `sr` you have `StreamReader`, what are the contents? Probably there are invalid numbers between `delimeters`

Comment: Did you try debugging the code and checking what are the input data? I bet you get some non-digit data and try to cast it to integer with Convert.ToInt32 call.

Answer (score 0):

"Input string not in the correct format" means you're trying to parse an int from a nonsense string.

For example:

```
Convert.ToInt32("the letter q"); // this will throw that exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use nullable integers to track whether there was missing data.  Also, consider using int.TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32 to avoid the InvalidFormatException.  Example:

```
List<int> idList = new List<int>();
List<int?[]> valList = new List<int?[]>();
string line;
while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
{
    string[] lineParts = line.Split(delimiters);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[0]);
    idList.Add(id);

    int?[] vals = new int?[numTests];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        int parsed;
        if (!int.TryParse(lineParts[i + 1], out parsed))
            vals[i] = null;
        else
            vals[i] = parsed;
    }
    valList.Add(vals);
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
childIDs = idList.ToArray();
var values = valList.ToArray();
```